# Same data is returned in AngularJS Promise Chaining

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-promise, angularjs-http

I want to make 3 API calls when my page is loaded to bring the necessary data.
My application is in AngularJS#1.5.8. I am able to bring the data separately in service, but for some reason, in the controller the data of first API call is returned all 3 times.
There is no dependency between the 3 API calls.

Here is my controller code

```
// app.module.js
(function () {

  angular
    .module('SomeAppName', [])
    .controller('DDCtrl', DDCtrl);

  DDCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'ApiService']

  function DDCtrl($scope, ApiService) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.qddData = [];
    vm.rddData = [];
    vm.sddData = [];

    activate();

    function activate() {

      ApiService.getNumberData('api/get.first.data.php')
        .then(function (firstdata) {
          console.log(firstdata);
          vm.qddData = firstdata;
          return ApiService.getNumberData('api/get.second.data.php');
        })
        .then(function (seconddata) {
          console.log(seconddata); // logs firstdata instead of seconddata
          vm.rddData = seconddata;
          return ApiService.getNumberData('api/get.third.data.php');
        })
        .then(function (thirddata) {
          console.log(thirddata); // logs firstdata instead of thirddata
          vm.sddData = thirddata;
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err.data);
        });
    }
  }
})();
```

Here is my data service

```
// app.service.js
(function () {

  angular
    .module('SomeAppName')
    .factory('ApiService', ApiService);

  ApiService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];

  function ApiService($http, $q) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    return {
      getNumberData: getNumberData
    };

    function getNumberData(dictUrl) {
      return $http.get(apiUrl)
        .then(getRequestComplete)
        .catch(getRequestFailed);
    }

    function getRequestComplete(response) {
      console.log(response.data); // here the data is logged correctly
      deferred.resolve(response.data);
      return deferred.promise;
    }

    function getRequestFailed(error) {
      deferred.reject(error);
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threat is inside your `ApiService`, you are maintaining single `defer` object for all your `http` request which isn't correct. Rather I can say, you don't need to create your custom `promise`(its consider as anti-pattern). Just utilize promise return by `$http.get` & chain it via returning a data from its `success` callback.

**Code**

```
(function () {

  angular
    .module('SomeAppName')
    .factory('ApiService', ApiService);

  ApiService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];

  function ApiService($http, $q) {
    //no need to create a custom defer object at all
    //var deferred = $q.defer();

    return {
      getNumberData: getNumberData
    };

    function getNumberData(dictUrl) {
      return $http.get(apiUrl)
        .then(getRequestComplete)
        .catch(getRequestFailed);
    }

    function getRequestComplete(response) {
      return response.data; //return a data to chain promise with success
    }

    function getRequestFailed(error) {
      return $q.reject(error); //reject to call error function of subsequent chain promise
    }
  }

})();
```

Comment: Ahh, I see it now... @Pankaj
BTW If I was executing normal functions (not $http) then would it be right to create custom promise?

Comment: @overlord Glad to help youThanks ;)